# Cannot add a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using VS 2019 and when I try to add controller, gives me an error saying :

> There was an error running the selected code generator ' The value -1
>   is outside the acceptable range of [0,2147483647].Parameter name:
>   value'

Comment: Better to add screenshot.

Comment: The first thing I'd check is that my instance of Visual Studio, as well as the NuGet packages I'm using, are fully updated to the latest versions.  These types of errors are oftentimes due to bugs in individual packages/tools.

Comment: maybe nuget package has a mistake.Reload project edit . csproj and  check nuget package area.